# Using an jQuery Array instead of a string as a parameter for MultiDatesPicker for jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I'm using MultiDatesPicker v1.6.3 for jQuery UI (http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) to display a clickable calendar.

I want to use the addDates method to add pre selected dates to the calendar. like this - http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#pre-select-dates-demo

The documentation states that

> The parameter dates can be a string, a date object or an array (of strings or javascript date objects).

I want to add dates from an array I've created like this

```
var somedates = ['3-3-2015', '4-3-2015', '5-3-2015'];
```

But I can't work out how to use the array with the option.  It works if I use a sting with the option like

```
addDates: ['3-3-2015', '4-3-2015', '5-3-2015']
```

But how do I use the array?

Sorry if my terminology is poor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an array that consist of Date type objects, for example:

```
var date1 = new Date("03/09/2015");
var date1 = new Date("03/11/2015");
var dateArray = [date1, date1];
$('#yourdatepickername').multiDatesPicker({
                        addDates: dateArray});
```

Remember that you need to use the correct date format(in my case it was MM/dd/yyyy).

You can also use:

```
 var dateArray= ["09/03/2015", "11/03/2015"]
 $("#yourdatepickername").multiDatesPicker('addDates', dateArray);
```

The date format in this case must match the format that is set for the datepicker.

Comment: Thanks!  it was the "new Date" bit I was missing and the correct format.